# Comparing wildcard strings - both sides of the comparison wildcarded

Tags: sql, string, comparison, wildcard

The problem: I have events arriving with a compound key.  To simplify, let's say the key is:

> OS+hostname+somedetail

Some examples might be:

- `WIN+SERVER1+DB+PAY`
- `WIN+SERVER2+CPU_HIGH`

We have various teams who can subscribe to these with a SQL wildcarded string. For example, a windows admin might subscribe to `WIN+%` and a DBA might subscribe to `WIN+%+DB+%`.

We've made a rod for our own backs by not nailing this down at the start but it's been a classic case of making it work first then make it work better when we can. For performance reasons I want to minimize the number of overlapping subscriptions.  The data is both in excel and a MS SQL table.  The problem is that although SQL server will agree 
`WIN+%` is `LIKE WIN+SERVER1+DB+PAY` it doesn't seem to agree that `WIN+%` is `LIKE WIN+%+DB+%` in a  SQL `SELECT`. And most of the solutions I can google allow wildcards on only one side.

I think I can some of it by breaking one side of the wildcard comparison (which can be more complex) at each wildcard.

For example `WIN+%+DB+%` becomes `SELECT field WHERE field LIKE 'WIN+%" and field LIKE '%+DB+%'`

This seems to break down quite quickly, though possibly I could produce a list of likely cases.

I'm working through a book on regexes and suspect they might be of use once I get a better grip.  I have a fair toolkit on the server with access to more so am open to any solutions on most platforms.

In case anyone is interested - each match produces a ticket so 2 matches will produce 2 tickets and they may not cross refer causing extra work.  This is across several data centers and we have several thousand subscriptions in place - mainly auto-generated by a "part-of-the-problem" "solution".  On the plus side it keeps me in work.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions:

a) Think about breaking the big subscription strings into their parts. So you end with 3 columns: OS, HOSTNAME and DETAIL. Then you can query `... FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS WHERE event LIKE OS||'%' AND event LIKE '%'||HOST||'%' AND event LIKE '%'||DETAIL`.

b) You have 8 cases: no wildcard, only OS as wildcard, only HOST as wildcard, only DETAIL as wildcard, OS and HOST as wildcard, OS and DETAIL as wildcard, HOST and DETAIL as wildcard, all 3 as wildcard. For each of this you can write a seperate query handling it. This would function as you described. This would be a bad solution if you have much more cases cause it is not easy to extend.

Comment: b - actually it's 8 fields so 256 options.  Then again this could be built pretty easily in code and run overnight.  Thanks for the input - I'm going to think